# Querying the first entry of multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2017. I have a table `Part` and a table `Batch` and both are joined n:n in a table `PartBatch` with `PartId` and `BatchId` columns.

This is my starting point:

```
+---------+--------+
| BatchId | PartId |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 1      |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 2      |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 3      |
+---------+--------+
```

Further I have two tables `TastACommon` (holds common data, like DateTime) and `TestA` (holds individual data, like measurement data) that are in 1:n relationship (`TestACommon`:`TestA`, that is).

`TestACommon` has the column `BatchId` and `Closed` (bit).

```
+----+----------+---------+-----+
| Id | Closed   | BatchId | ... |
|    |          |         |     |
+----+----------+---------+-----+
| 1  | true     | 1       |     |
+----+----------+---------+-----+
| 2  | false    | 1       |     |
+----+----------+---------+-----+
| 3  | true     | 2       |     |
+----+----------+---------+-----+
```

`TestA` has the columns `PartId`, `Success` (bit), and `TestACommonId`.

```
+----+---------------+--------+---------+-----+
| Id | TestACommonId | PartId | Success | ... |
|    |               |        |         |     |
+----+---------------+--------+---------+-----+
| 1  | 1             | 1      | true    | ... |
+----+---------------+--------+---------+-----+
| 2  | 1             | 2      | false   | ... |
+----+---------------+--------+---------+-----+
| 3  | 2             | 1      | true    | ... |
+----+---------------+--------+---------+-----+
```

[image]

I am now trying to create a query that puts out ALL the entries from `PartBatch` (`BatchId` and `PartId`) and a bit that indicates if there exists ANY closed and successful `TestA` this combination of part and batch. Same for some equivalent TestB, TestC, ...

```
+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
| BatchId | PartId | AnySuccessTestA | AnySuccessTestB | ... |
+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
| 1       | 1      | true            | true            | ... |
+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
| 1       | 2      | true            | false           | ..  |
+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
| 1       | 3      | false           | true            | ... |
+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----+
```

What I have tried is this. Understanding how to handle the triangle between `PartBatch`, `TestA` and `TestACommon` is giving me hard time. I have not even touched the 'ANY'-problem.

```
SELECT pb.PartId, pb.BatchId, IFNULL(a.IsSuccess, 0)
FROM PartBatch as pb
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT aci.IsClosed, aci.Id, aci.BatchId
  FROM TestACommon as aci
  WHERE aci.IsClosed = 1 an aci.BatchId = pb.BatchId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT ai.Success, ai.TestACommonId, ai.PartId
      FROM TestA as ai
       WHERE ai.Success = 1) As a ON a.TestACommonId = aci.Id)
AS ao ON ao.PartId == pb.PartId
```

As always I think there might already something like this on StackOverflow, but I don't really know what to look for.

====EDIT====

My own words 'Understanding how to handle the triangle between `PartBatch`, `TestA` and `TestACommon` ...' gave me a good idea.

1. Instead of `LEFT OUTER` I should do a (inner) `JOIN` between `TestA` and `TestACommon` and look if `Success` and `Closed` is ever true.

```
SELECT aci.BatchId, ai.PartId, a.Success
FROM TestACommon AS aci
JOIN TestA AS ai ON ai.TestACommonId = aci.Id
WHERE aci.Finalized = 1 AND ai.Success=1
```

If I want to indeed see all entries of `PartBatch` I need to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to combine them. That give me:

```
SELECT 
    pb.PartId, pb.BatchId, ISNULL(a.Success, 0) AS SuccessTestA
FROM 
    PartBatch AS pb

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT aci.BatchId, ai.PartId, a.Success
 FROM TestACommon AS aci
 JOIN TestA AS ai ON ai.TestACommonId = aci.Id
 WHERE aci.Closed = 1 AND ai.Success = 1) AS a ON a.BatchId = pb.BatchId  
                                               AND a.PartId = pb.PartId
```

So far so good. Now I only need to solve the ANY-problem. I might look into cross apply, if I remember that correctly.

===Edit2===
The last part was easier than I thought. For the 'inner' `SELECT` I only needed to add `TOP 1`:

```
SELECT 
    pb.PartId, pb.BatchId, ISNULL(a.Success, 0) AS SuccessTestA
FROM 
    PartBatch AS pb
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT TOP 1 aci.BatchId, ai.PartId, a.Success
 FROM TestACommon AS aci
 JOIN TestA AS ai ON ai.TestACommonId = aci.Id
 WHERE aci.Closed = 1 AND ai.Success = 1) AS a ON a.BatchId = pb.BatchId  
                                               AND a.PartId = pb.PartId
```

Also, as *Charlieface* pointed out the FKs of `TestA` for `PartId` and `TestACommon` for `BatchId` should point to `PartBatch` and not to `Part` and `Batch`.

Comment: Could be wrong, but to me this looks denormalized. Can we not derive `PartBatch` via `TestACommon` and `TestA`?

Comment: Mhh, but that way I would only get all the `PartBatch` with an existing `TestACommon` and an existing `TestA`. Or do I miss something? I basically need an overview of all existing `PartBatch` and if they have passed any `TestA` or not. Never attending the `TestA` should correctly lead to a `false`.

Comment: Then I would imagine the relationship between `Part` and `TestA` is wrong. Maybe it should be `PartId, BatchId` and FK to `PartBatch`, not directly to `Part`? Then we can say that a part, which is in a particular batch, has had a test

Comment: I think you are right. But it's not obvious that to me right now.

Comment: I would migrate this to [dba.se], they have more experience in DB design

Comment: oh, is there an actual function in StackOverflow that allow migration or do you mean 'ask there again'?

Comment: I've flagged it now for moderators attention, they will migrate it